# If light could bend around a person ,would that make the person invisible?

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

If we place an object such as a coin in front of the light source ,e.g a candle we cant see the candle through the coin but if the size of the coin would be comparable to the wavelength of visible light the we can see the candle through the coin because light would bend around it ... So my question is  , can a device like this be designed[image: the device here]

a device that generates electromagnetic waves whose wavelength initially is in the visible region then whose wavelength continuously increases then bends around the person then its wavelength sort of decreases till it reaches the eye of the receiver as visible light .So the person would be invisible to the reciever. Is such a device possible? Is my idea stupid? And if at all we are able to make such a device would it happen just like i said or is my idea just wrong?

Comment: There is a military product called HyperStealth that claims to perform a similar function.  From the website it is "a material that renders the target completely invisible by bending light waves around the target."  I am friends with a fellow who is involved with this company, but I can't make a judgement on the claims.

Comment: That,s new information . But from what I read in the net I guess its some kind of cloak for soldiers .Any Idea how that works@foolishmuse

Comment: no, I don't.  But I asked my friend and he confirmed that "it really works in the right conditions." It's being held top secret for now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, light can only travel in **straight linear paths**, so that machine would be implausible and also it can't be plausible because light would have to travel around the person (it wouldn't work as your drawing suggested because the light would have to change its frequency to become a higher wave) and because it can only travel in a straight line (as I said) ***not plausible***!

However this is a great mind experiment.
If we could somehow create circular (going in a circe) light then it would be possible.  [image: [Different point of view]
BUT if any other light is present then I don't know if it could work.

Comment: In Ray optics we consider light to be travelling in straight paths for the reason that the wavelength of visible light is much smaller than day to day objects and it is approximated to travel in straight path

Comment: And i think my diagram and yours is the same . I drew the cross sectional view , you drew the view as seen from above

Comment: And i dont think light waves go in circles . Picture them as wave riplets in water you drew the view from above , i drew the cross sectional one. I really doubt your knowledge about the difference between ray and wave optics

Comment: And what do you mean by if any other light is present? Light is an electromagnetic wave and all electromagnetic waves behave in the same way

Comment: Oh if there is any background light thats what I meant (then it would be reflected of the "person" or some of that background light would be canceled out)